# Problems moving move Anypoint Studio 7.4 to 7.9?

Tags: mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

Are there any know issues when upgrading to Studio 7.9 regarding third party connectors?

After importing / opening my projects all external connectors (SAP & Salesforce) fail to be imported:

```
Resolving dependency com.sap.conn.jco:com.sap.conn.jco.sapjco3 found the following exceptions:
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to collect dependencies at com.sap.conn.jco:libsapjco3:so:external-library:3.x.x
```

Same for Salesforce:

```
Resolving dependency com.mulesoft.connectors:mule-salesforce-connector found the following exceptions:
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to collect dependencies at com.mulesoft.connectors:mule-salesforce-connector:jar:mule-plugin:9.4.0 -> com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:jar:2.2.10
...
```

**Update:**

I think it's an Maven issue, e.g. in the old POM-file the url for the anypoint repository is "https://maven.eu1.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/maven" whereas if I create a new project in 7.9 it is "https://maven.eu1.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v2/maven"

Also in the studio settings it is maven 3.3.9 VS 3.6.3 in the new.

So, should I have done a kind of pom-conversion? Or manually downgrade the maven version?

Comment: Are you using the same user? and did you upgrade Studio using the upgrade feature or did you download Studio 7.9 as a new application?

Comment: It is the same user, yes. I had to get a new computer, so, I have a fresh studio installation on a new machine (including the mentioned os update).

Answer (score 0):

Probably a Maven issue from having a new machine. If you have a new $HOME/.m2 directory, you are losing manually added dependencies (the SAP ones?) and your customized Maven settings.xml inside that directory.

If you don't have MuleSoft enterprise repositories configured follow the instructions on the documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb#referencing-mulesofts-enterprise-repositories

If you had any manually added dependencies into your local Maven repository of the old computer, you will need to install them again in the new computer.